# How to get a single value form multiple values in a Mysql field

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a mail table where i have the following fields.

```
id    mail_to    mail_subject    mail_message
1     6,9,10     Test Mail       Test Message
2     4,8,6      Test Mail       Test Message
```

Values stored in mail_to field are id of users.
I want to display all the mail where mail_to is 6. How to use the where condition in this case.

I tried to achieve the result with this query but it did not work.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_profile_inbox WHERE mail_to = '6' ;
```

Can you guys help on this one.

Comment: `SUBSTRING` may lead towards wrong output in some particular cases like `mail_to = 9,66,10`

Comment: I would suggest change your table design.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET()` for that:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_profile_inbox WHERE FIND_IN_SET('6',mail_to)
```

Comment: This is a **nice solution** if you don't want to change your table design. But still I would suggest change your table design.

Comment: Why do i need to change my table design. Is there anything wrong in this design.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `REGEXP` also.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_profile_inbox WHERE mail_ to REGEXP '[[:<:]]6[[:>:]]'
```